# Como mudar o navegador padrão do sistema?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Como eu mudo o navegador padrão do sistema? Ao abrir um *link*, ir para o meu navegador com o *link* já aberto?

Já fiz para ele reconhecer os *links* ao iniciar o navegador:

```vb
Public Overrides Sub OnLoad() Handles Me.Load
     If Not (Command = Nothing)
          If (Url.IsWellFormatedUriString(Command, UriKind.Absolute))
               WebBrowser1.Navigate(Command)
          End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Beleza, e agora para abrir um *link* como navegador padrão (o meu navegador)?

Comment: A pergunta do título é diferente da pergunta do corpo, o que de fato você quer saber?

Comment: Só quero saber como eu deixo o meu navegador que fiz como o padrão do sistema, o navegador que abre os links automáticamente....

Comment: Eu acho que você não fez o que está pensando que fez, mas tudo bem, cada um faz o que quiser. Você quer escrever um código que faça a troca ou só quer mudar isto no Windows?

Comment: Quando você instala o Google Chrome ele mostra "Deseja tornar seu navegador padrão", se você marca ele fica como navegador padrão, ele mudou automáticamente no Windows, quero saber como ele fez isso, no caso um código que faça isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só vou fazer um alerta. Você vai trocar um navegador que milhares de pessoas extremamente competentes trabalharam por anos por algo que você fez? Fique à vontade.

O segredo é colocar no registro do Windows as informações certas para tornar o "seu navegador" o padrão do sistema.

Eu achei um código que pode te ajudar em uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24558012/221800).

```
Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".htm", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".html", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".shtml", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".xht", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".xhtml", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"http\shell\open\command", true).SetValue("", "firefox.exe");
Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"https\shell\open\command", true).SetValue("", "firefox.exe");
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command", true).SetValue("", "firefox.exe");
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\https\shell\open\command", true).SetValue("", "firefox.exe");
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice", true).SetValue("progId", "FirefoxURL");
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice", true).SetValue("progId", "FirefoxURL");
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice", true).SetValue("progId", "FirefoxURL");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/RegisterBrowser.vb).

Obviamente que no exemplo foi usado o Firefox, você deve trocar para o que for mais adequado para o "seu navegador".

Evidentemente o software já precisa estar instalado (pelo menos copiado). Pode ser que no instalador permita fazer isto de forma mais simples. Consulte a documentação do seu instalador.